# Need to provide a SettingKey from a plugin I use in my sbt plugin

Tags: scala, sbt

I am using the [s3 resolver plugin](https://github.com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/blob/master/src/main/scala/fm/sbt/S3ResolverPlugin.scala#L39) and would like to override it in my `AutoPlugin`.

I have tried added the value to `projectSettings` and `globalSettings`.

**Error**

```
not found: value s3CredentialsProvider
[error]     s3CredentialsProvider := s3CredentialsProviderChain
```

Code

```
lazy val s3CredentialsProviderChain = {bucket: String =>
    new AWSCredentialsProviderChain(
      new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider(),
      CustomProvider.create(bucket)
    )
  }

 override lazy val projectSettings = Seq(
publishTo := {
   if (Keys.isSnapshot.value) {
      Some("my-snapshots" at "s3://rest-of-stuff")
    } else {
      Some("my-releases" at "s3://rest-of-stuff")
    }
  },
  s3CredentialsProvider := s3CredentialsProviderChain
)
```

The plugin code I'm working on does not define any custom settings of it's own thus has no `autoImport` of it's own.

**Update**

I have been unable to resolve the `fm.sbt.S3ResolverPlugin` in `MyPlugin` and the code won't compile.

I have tried adding it to `enablePlugins` on `MyPlugin`'s build.sbt as well as adding it to the `dependencies` like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sts" % amazonSDKVersion,
  "com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.17.0"
)
```

I get an error from sbt which I've asked below:

[sbt fails to resolve a plugin as dependency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54584762/sbt-fails-to-resolve-a-plugin-as-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an AutoPlugin in `project` directory. You need to add this to `plugins.sbt`.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.16.0")
```

If you create an independent plugin, add this to `build.sbt` of the plugin

```
sbtPlugin := true
addSbtPlugin("com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.16.0")
```

`autoImport` does not work in `scala` files that are compiled for `sbt`, ie plugins for example. You have specify `import`s statements as in simple scala program. Something like this

```
import fm.sbt.S3ResolverPlugin
import sbt._

object TestPlugin extends AutoPlugin {

  override def requires = S3ResolverPlugin

  override def trigger = allRequirements

  override def projectSettings: Seq[Def.Setting[_]] = Seq(
    S3ResolverPlugin.autoImport.s3CredentialsProvider := ???
  )
}
```

Note that to enable `TestPlugin`, you have to call `enablePlugins(S3ResolverPlugin)` in `build.sbt`

Comment: I have had some issues with sbt not resolving the plugin correctly as a dependency. I have updated the question with the same.

Comment: I have tried using `enablePlugins` as an alternative but it did not work either.