# sbt fails to resolve a plugin as dependency

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

I have a plugin called `MyPlugin` which needs to update a value from another plugin. I have thus added that plugin as a dependency based on

[Logging from an sbt plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545388/logging-from-an-sbt-plugin)

[Need to provide a SettingKey from a plugin I use in my sbt plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54567342/need-to-provide-a-settingkey-from-a-plugin-i-use-in-my-sbt-plugin)

However, sbt fails to resolve the dependency `fm-sbt-s3-resolver`. What is the appropriate way of including the dependency on the project?

I have tried adding it to `enablePlugins` on `MyPlugin`'s build.sbt as well as adding it to the `dependencies` like this:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-java-sdk-sts" % amazonSDKVersion,
  "com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.17.0"
)
```

In `MyPlugin.scala`:

```
import fm.sbt.S3ResolverPlugin

object MyPlugin {
  override def requires = S3ResolverPlugin

  override lazy val globalSettings = Seq(
    resolvers += repos
    S3ResolverPlugin.autoImport.s3CredentialsProvider := s3CredentialsProviderChain
  )
}
```

I get this error from sbt:

> I can find the project on [this url](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver_2.10_0.13/0.17.0/fm-sbt-s3-resolver-0.17.0.pom) on the Maven Central Repo.

```
module not found: com.frugalmechanic#fm-sbt-s3-resolver;0.17.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.ivy2/local/com.frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/fm-sbt-s3-resolver-0.17.0.pom
[warn] ==== local-preloaded-ivy: tried
[warn]   /Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/com.frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local-preloaded: tried
[warn]   file:////Users/localuser/.sbt/preloaded/com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/fm-sbt-s3-resolver-0.17.0.pom
[warn] ==== sonatype-public: tried
[warn]   https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/public/com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-s3-resolver/0.17.0/fm-sbt-s3-resolver-0.17.0.pom
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.frugalmechanic#fm-sbt-s3-resolver;0.17.0: not found
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.frugalmechanic:fm-sbt-s3-resolver:0.17.0 (/Users/localuser/lendi/core/scala/lendi-plugin/build.sbt#L13-17)
[warn]        +- com.mypackage.my-plugin:0.0.6 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.frugalmechanic#fm-sbt-s3-resolver;0.17.0: not found
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.frugalmechanic#fm-sbt-s3-resolver;0.17.0: not found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking into [frugalmechanic group in maven](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/frugalmechanic/), 
It seems that following pom exists:

```
fm-sbt-s3-resolver_2.12_1.0/0.17.0/fm-sbt-s3-resolver-0.17.0.pom
                  ^^^^^^^^^ this is scala version, and sbt version.
```

This path is not a normal one which consists of group id, and artifact id package version since it has `_2.12_1.0` in it. This means that plugin is targeted to scala version `2.12`, and sbt version `1.0`.

Therefore adding plugin as dependency, you have to use `Defaults.sbtPluginExtra()` and tell that you need specific scala version and plugin version, as below:

```
libraryDependencies += Defaults.sbtPluginExtra("com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.17.0", "1.0", "2.12")
```

first argument is package, second argument is sbt version, and third argument is scala version.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want `addSbtPlugin` so you do not have to worry about the Scala or SBT version (it will be handled automatically):

```scala
addSbtPlugin("com.frugalmechanic" % "fm-sbt-s3-resolver" % "0.17.0")
```

Here is an example of it being used in another SBT plugin: [built.sbt for fm-sbt-common](https://github.com/frugalmechanic/fm-sbt-common/blob/01d96ba0fcd89ebd53c042bc072d426d8d66ecc4/build.sbt#L31)